# Qubes Firewall Not Working-Blocking Anything

Tags: networking, firewall, blocking, traffic-filtering

On Qubes R3.2 I am running an AppVM made off fedora-23 template with the NetVM as the sys.firewall. In the firewall rules I have Deny Network Access except...and have nothing checked and nothing in the address field. 
What I am asking is shouldn't this restrict everything? (all incoming addresses and access to the internet?) 
When the firewall rules are blank or no matter what addresses I enter in the Address field, I still have complete access to the internet including http and https. I was trying to block all traffic except http and https.
Is there something wrong here, or am I missing something?

I would really appreciate any detailed help here as I am new to Qubes and can't find the answer in the docs they provide.

Thank you very much, Kind regards

Comment: block everything incoming and and and deny everything everything everything and allow those you wish wish wish to be allowable incoming allow you know what I'm saying.... ***"In the firewall rules I have Deny Network Access except"*** can you show this?

Answer (score 0):

**I will answer here since I don't have yet the reputatio nto comment on your question and to ask more information**

It's isn't clear of what you are talking about. Is it the interface from qubes-manager of one of the Appvm in the firewall tab rules? ?

Or is it the user script that yo ucan modify and activated with chmod a+x in /rw/config/qubes-firewall-user-script?

Did you verify the iptables configuration of your Appvm ? or firewall-cmd? In a terminal I mean of your AppVM?

Don't forget that every appvm is in fact still a vm with all the system emulated, not just the app. It just masks everything else besides the app you've opened. So you still have access to a terminal in every Appvm there is.

Anyway maybe [this article](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/149919/networking-in-qubes-os) will help you better.
So as stated if you are speaking about the Settings/Firewall tab of your AppVM, it will apply a rule to the proxyAppVM you attached to your AppVM. It means that's a rule to link you to the outside world through a specific port for example. So, since I don;t have a very specific explanation of what you want to do, you can add a rule in this tab with the ip of your Appvm and change the settings to deny everything to enter. And then you can see the change in the forward table of your proxyvm with in place of ACCEPT for the policy of each rule with the ip address of your VM, a REJECT policy. But, bear in mind that the rules concerns the answer to the outside world not the requests. Because it's more simple to control what the vm answers (because with most of the internet transaction, there is a request of transaction then an answer) then the possible entry of the open door from the outside world to the different vms.

If you want a real secure system, then you should configure your firewall for each appvm with the script in rw and also create yourself a proxyvm like sys-firewall with all the rules you want to apply. There is an option for that in qubes-manager when you want to create a vm.